# BC30456:'ddTrustStatus2_Load' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'

Tags: vb.net

I was building this solution and debugging it and I came across this error message:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30456:'ddTrustStatus2_Load' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx.'

Line 616: <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Trust Status" HeaderText='Trust Status" SortExpression="TrustStatusId">
Line 617: <EditItemTemplate>
Line 618: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddTrustStatus2" runat="server" Width="125px" Enabled="false" DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceTrustStatus2" DataTextField="TrustStatusName" DataValueField="TrustStatusId" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("TrustStatusId") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddTrustStatus2_SelectedIndexChanged" OnLoad="ddTrustStatus2_Load">
Line 619: </asp:DropDownList>
Line 620: <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblrevini" CssClass="RQFields" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

Line 618 is highlighted red when the error occurs. I've researched a possible solution and some of the resolutions that I've been coming across is that I needed to add a CodeBehind, Inherits and a page declarative. But it seems as though I've already have the CodeBehind and Inherits.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="SSITM._Default" %>
```

Comment: Is this coming up in VStudio?  Does VStudio have any other build errors?

Comment: Also, please confirm: in your default.aspx.vb file, are you sure that you have a (protected) sub called ddTrustStatus2_Load()

Comment: So far, I'm not seeing any protected sub

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your aspx file is referring to an event in your code-behind, which is not there.  You have two choices:

1) Remove the reference to the missing event handler.  In your aspx file, on line 618, remove this text: `OnLoad="ddTrustStatus2_Load"`

2) You could add the missing even handler, that your aspx page is referring to.  In your default.aspx.vb file, add the following code

```vb
Protected Sub ddTrustStatus2_Load()
    'you decide if you need some code here or not
End Sub
```